# javascript Object.assign() without overriding fields

Tags: javascript, object, data-structures, ecmascript-6, assign

Is there any way to merge two objects, like `Object.assign(a, b)`, but I want the same field in `a` keeps its origin value (without overriding from `b`).

```
a = {x: 1, y: 2}
b = {y: 3, z: 4}

Object.assign(a, b)
// Now we get a = {x: 1, y: 3, z: 4}, so what if I want {x: 1, y: 2, z: 4}?
console.log(a)
```

> Note: thanks for the efforts from the answers, the key requirements for the question is:

1. modify `a`
2. not too much code
3. not too slow

Comment: `Object.assign(b, a)`?

Comment: `const merged = {...b, ...a};` or just `Object.assign(b,a,)`

Comment: @evolutionxbox This will modify `b`. The OP wants to modify `a`

Comment: @jabaa you are correct. It should probably be `Object.assign({}, b, a)` then?

Comment: @evolutionxbox This won't modify both variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the perfect solution is `lodash.defaults`.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#defaults

```
import _ from 'lodash'

a = {x: 1, y: 2}
b = {y: 3, z: 4}

_.defaults(a, b)

// Outputs {x:1, y:2, z:4}, perfectly as expected.
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify the `a` reference (like you seem to be wanting to do from your example), you could do:

```js
const a = {x: 1, y: 2};
const b = {y: 3, z: 4};

Object.assign(a, {...b, ...a});
console.log(a);
```

This essentially says, replace the overlapping properties in `b` with those from `a`, and then merge this replaced object into `a`.

Above, the `{...b, ...a}` first merges `a` with `b`, so `a` overwrites properties in `b`, giving us:

```js
{y: 3, z: 4, x: 1, y: 2}
// evalutes to
{z: 4, x: 1, y: 2}
```

Now we merge this result into `a` with the `Object.assign()` call:

```js
{x: 1, y: 2, z: 4, x: 1, y: 2}
// evalutes to
{z: 4, x: 1, y: 2}
// ie:
{x: 1, y: 2, z: 4}
```

---

**Edit:**
To meet your requirements, use a regular `for...in` loop, it's efficient, doesn't require much code (especially if you remove the blocks), and modifies `a`:

```js
const a = {x: 1, y: 2};
const b = {y: 3, z: 4};

for(const key in b) a[key] ??= b[key];
console.log(a); // {"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 4}
```

The above works if your values won't be nullish (`null`/`undefined`) as it uses logical nullish assignment ([`??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)), otherwise, you can replace the assignment with:

```js
a[key] = key in a ? a[key] : b[key];
```

Comment: It works but ugly, all fields in `a` will be assigned entirly through once.

Comment: @AlfredHuang if you need something more efficient, you can use `for..in`. (see edit)

Comment: The most effort for the shortest code and the best practise solution. Thanks.

Comment: But the last solution should have an if clause to exclude the existing keys in a. `for(const key of a) if (!(key in a)) a[key] = b[key];`

Comment: @AlfredHuang yes, sorry, I had it wrong. We should be iterating over the keys in `b`, and then updating the keys in `a` to those in `b` if they don't exist. I've update my answer now.

Comment: Finally I found the perfect solution is `lodash.defaults`. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#defaults

Comment: @AlfredHuang that will work, but it uses lodash (which you did not mention in your question). But as shown above, this can be done in a pretty straightforward way using vanilla JS, so there is no need to install a third-party library just for something like this imo. If you are already using lodash in your project, using something like that is fine, but nothing in your question indicates that you are. You can wrap the above in a function if you want it to be reusable.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to this is to avoid using Object.assign and use spread operator as by doing so you'll achieve your goal with simple logic. In spread operator, the rightmost element overwrites the left one.

```
a = {x: 1, y: 2};
b = {y: 3, z: 4};
        
result = {...b, ...a}; 
result2 = {...a, ...b};
console.log(result); // {x: 1, y: 2, z: 4} 
console.log(result2); // {x: 1, y: 3, z: 4} 

//if you don't want to create new object and just modify a then
Object.assign(a, {...b, ...a});
console.log(a); // {x: 1, y: 2, z: 4}
```

Comment: It looks like OP wants to modify the `a` object reference from their example (and not create a new object)

Comment: Yes. the solution doesn't modify a.

Comment: Yes agreed @NickParsons

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = { x: 1, y: 2 };
let temp = { ...a };
let b = { y: 3, z: 4 };

Object.assign(a, b);
Object.assign(a, temp);

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.entries` and filter out keys that are already in `a`.

eg.

```js
a = {x: 1, y: 2}
b = {y: 3, z: 4}

//Object.assign(a, b)
// Now we get a = {x: 1, y: 3, z: 4}, so what if I want {x: 1, y: 2, z: 4}?
Object.assign(a, Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(b).
    filter(([k])=>!(k in a))));

console.log(a)
```